# Copy Row and Delete

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets - 'Form Responses 1' and 'Students'.

When I run the function below, it copies all data from 'Form Responses 1' to 'Students' where I'll need to massage the data further in the second sheet. After I copied, I want that particular row to be deleted from 'Form Responses 1'. The next round when I run the function again (when there is new data in 'Form Responses 1'), it will append to 'Students' accordingly.

Would very much appreciate if you could advise how can I amend my codes below, thanks!

```
function Copy() 
{
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet ID'); //replace with source ID
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
    var range = ss.getRange('A:V'); //assign the range you want to copy
    var data = range.getValues();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var getRow = range.getRow();

    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet ID'); //replace with destination ID
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Students');  

    ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

    /*delete function is missing*/
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want a question answered it would be great if you would edit your post to contain a question. What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: Hi not sure why you want to delete the responses from form response. An alternative would be to use an importrange* to pull the values to a new sheet. *Importrange is a native Google Sheets function. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bit of code should achieve the desire result, otherwise it is a good place to start. The code is pretty simple, so I put all the explanations in the comments of the code.

To use this code you can create a Stand alone script. **(Does not need to be bound to a spreadsheet.)** Copy Primary and Secondary code into two seperate tabs. **(See the attached picture.)** Once you have changed the IDs in the two scripts, run the primary script and you should see the desired result. ***(Be aware the all data in the form responses will be cleared.)***

Hope this helps, and feel free to ask if you are not sure. Just note at this point I will be directing you to the documentation instead of trying to explain how certain methods/calls work:

### Primary Code

```
function copy_Delete(){

var ss, sheet;
var lastRow, lastColumn;
var responseData;

//Get Spreadsheet and Sheet name for Form Responses Sheet  
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_ID_HERE");
sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

//Gets a numerical value representing the last row and last column where data is entered.  
lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

//Get all the data in the From Responses Sheet and put it all in an array.
responseData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1, lastColumn).getValues();

//Call the destination function and pass the array to it. Then clear form responses of all data.
destination(responseData);
sheet.clear();
}
```

### Secondary Code

```
    function destination(responseData){

    var ss, sheet, form;
    var numRows, numColumns, lastRow;

    //Get Spreadsheet and Sheet name for your destination sheet 
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR ID HERE");
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Destination Sheet");

    //Get the dimensions of the array and the last row of the spreadsheet.
    numRows = responseData.length;
    numColumns = responseData[0].length;
    lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    //Using the dimensions above,we push our array from the previous function into our new sheet.
    sheet.getRange(lastRow +1, 1, numRows, numColumns).setValues(responseData);

    //Get form and delete all responses.
    form = FormApp.openById('YOUR_FORM_ID_HERE');
    form.deleteAllResponses();
    }
```

### Attached example

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much New_2_Code. It almost perfect with a little glitch whereby all new transactions coming into 'Form Responses 1' is not starting from the beginning of the row, which then created empty rows in the Destination sheet. What is it that I need to reset to make it start from row 1?

Btw, the reason why I needed to clear all rows in ''Form Responses 1' is so that whatever changes I make in Destination sheet will not be overwritten when I run the function again. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm not sure about a better way to do it. I am sure there is, just can't think of any right now. With regards new responses starting on a different line: The reason for that is you would need to delete the responses from your form as well. This being a standalone script it is totally possible. I will edit my response slightly to add deletion of responses.

Comment: Looking forward to the codes, thanks so much Mr New :)

Comment: Hehe Mr New... :D - I have edited the Secondary Code, there is a small change right at the bottom that will remove all responses from your form.

Comment: Can't seem to find your name anywhere else :D The updated script managed to clear all responses but it is not starting from first row yet. Hmmm, more tweaks needed I guess.

Comment: When you say it's not starting on the first row... You mean if someone submits a response to your form the response is not saved just under the headers? In other words there is a number of blank rows and then the response is saved? (Blank rows correspond to the number of previous responses.) That doesn't sound right. Clearing responses from the form and the sheet should result in new responses being saved directly under the headers. (Row 2) If it's not doing this could I suggest deleting your current response sheet and have google forms create you a new response sheet. (Then link those up.)

Comment: Hi :) Yes your statements above are correct. I've unlink the form and created a new Response Sheet and it is still the same - new response is not saved on the row below header :(

Comment: Aah okay I see what is wrong here. The script is clearing the contents, but in fact the rows need to be deleted. See the following post and see if you can come right. If not, leave a comment. Also please consider marking as an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023382/google-spreadsheet-doesnt-start-at-top-when-responses-are-cleared

Comment: It's working now! Yoohooo! Thank you so much Mr New for your help and patience! Have a good weekend :)

Comment: Good day @New_2_Code! I'm wondering if you could help me with a different question I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530247/retrieving-data-and-updating-row-in-different-sheet. Any advice would be much appreciated :)